# Having html and wordpress on the same directory

Tags: html, wordpress, redirect

I have a WordPress site with a couple of posts on it. To this site I need to add a few HTML pages (including index.html). I need both of them to work properly.

The home page should be the index.html page, and all its links(HTML pages).
The previous site URL's i.e. WordPress URL's should also work.

I put them together and the index.html page displays as home page, the subpages(HTML) also work fine. Although all WordPress URL's are re-directing to the index.html itself.

Is this possible? How do I make the old WordPress URL's work fine (i.e. not redirect the index.html page)?

Comment: Try installing WordPress in a subfolder. See [Giving WordPress Its Own Directory](http://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory)

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with issues like this, I like to create [page templates](http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates) in Wordpress (with page names like About, Projects, etc.) And then I create a .php file using the slug title of it (so a projects page will correspond to a .php file called 'page-projects.php'

One example being I make a page called 'about', then I create 'page-about.php' in my Wordpress directory. The [Wordpress Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy) will, along the way, look for a .php file called 'page-about.php'

A solution like this is great because those pages are linked through your site, so using /about or /projects will bring you to the proper pages instead of redirecting to the main page (because it redirects to your index when Wordpress can't find any other suitable template to display)

Comment: Here's a [flowchart](http://codex.wordpress.org/images/1/18/Template_Hierarchy.png) of the Hierarchy.